# Prevent interface name from going public in OSX bundle

Tags: xcode, macos, cocoa, bundle

I have a set of OSX plugin bundles written in C++ with Cocoa (without using interface builder and all that), and all are using the same custom `@interface` class as part of their inner framework (it inherits from NSView).  It's quite simple;

```
@interface C_CustomView : NSView
- (BOOL)performKeyEquivalent:(NSEvent*)event;
@end

@implementation C_CustomView
- (BOOL)performKeyEquivalent:(NSEvent*)event {
    [super keyDown:event];
    return YES;
}
@end
```

However, when the host application loads multiple of my plugins at the same time, I get as much warnings in the XCode log, stating:

> objc[4144]: Class C_CustomView is implemented in both <bundle 1's
>   path> and <bundle 2's path>. One of the two will be used. Which one is
>   undefined.

I presume this is a warning only, since my plugins seem to work OK for all I can see.  I suspect this class is exported as a public symbol?  I however would like this message to just go away :)

Is there some XCode compiler setting I can tweak, or some extra code I can add to the custom class to prevent it from being exported, if that is the cause?  I'm quite the XCode/OSX coding noob, so sorry if I missed something obvious.

Comment: problem:classes with the same name that are trying to load into same namespace. Hiding them won't help as runtime will load them into one namespace. Solution is either to have unique class name (3 letter prefix is the norm, 2 letter prefix norm for Apple) or rearchitecture your app and bundle loading

Comment: @MarekH Ooof...  Didn't expect these things to be process-global.  I thought each plugin bundle having their own copy of the class would not clash.  The problem is that the class is defined in a common source file between all plugins (they all need the same thing), and it is nested deep within the common framework file hierarchy.  I can thus only apply such a per-plugin prefix by using a unique per-plugin project-wide macro definition, which seems ugly to add just for this.  Thanks for the answer though!

Comment: @MarekH If you make a proper answer of your comment I can properly mark it as the answer, if you care for some extra rep score :)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Objective-C runtime is trying to load the same class `C_CustomView` into one namespace.

Standard way of naming Objective-C classes uses prefixes:[developer.apple.com](https://developer.apple.com/library/archive/documentation/Cocoa/Conceptual/CodingGuidelines/Articles/NamingBasics.html)

> Prefixes are an important part of names in programmatic interfaces.
>   They differentiate functional areas of software. Usually this software
>   comes packaged in a framework or (as is the case of Foundation and
>   Application Kit) in closely related frameworks. Prefixes protect
>   against collisions between symbols defined by third-party developers
>   and those defined by Apple (as well as between symbols in Apple’s own
>   frameworks).
>
> A prefix has a prescribed format. It consists of two or three
>   uppercase letters and does not use underscores or “sub prefixes.”

Prefixes are used to prevent this conflicts.

My recommendation is to extract the reused class to own bundle/framework and import this framework where it's needed.

Also as per citation upper one should not use underscores when naming classes. Prefix + CamelCase is the norm for Objective-C.

PS: Not sure about Swift details but there is no need for prefixes there (assume it doesn't share namespace)